# Manipulation of cursor data

Tags: mongodb, php-5.3

My jason object has this data now

```
{"":{"gid":102,
"names":{"firstName":"Stive",
"middleInitial":"Jr",
"lastName":"Martin"},
"job":{"departmentID":102,
"jobTitleID":100,
"hireDate":"1/02/2000",
"terminationDate":"1/12/2007"}, 
 "beeper":"5656",
 "email1":"info@soft-amis.com",
 "fax":"21-321-23223",
 "phoneMobile":"32-434-3433",
"phoneOffice":"82-900-8993"},
"login":{"employeeID":"eID102",
"password":"password",
"superUser":true,
"lastLoginDate":"1/12/2007",
"regexp":{},
 "date":{}},
"comment":{"PCDATA":"comment"},
"roles":[{"role":102},
{"role":103}]}}
```

I want to remove first 4 characters ie **{"":** and last character **}**

Could someone please help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform an update to specify that each field is top-level and not contained in an embedded document.

sample input document:

```
 {"":
       {
        "gid":102,
        "names":{"firstName":"Stive"}
       }
 }
```

Update command

```
db.collection.update({".gid":102},{gid:102, names: {firstName:"Stive"}})
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating/

Comment: I got this data after suppressing _id field ie..      $cursor=$Content->find(array("gid" => "102"),array("_id"=>0)); $array = iterator_to_array($cursor);  $jasonobj=json_encode($array);var_dump($jasonobj);

Comment: So is there a way to remove it without updating the DB?

Comment: What is your end goal? You don't need to update the database; you can manipulate the document client-side. It's possible to retrieve the values of each embedded field (names, middleInitial, etc.) using dot notation, and you can create a new object with the values of these fields in your application.

Comment: My end goal is to display this jason object in a an editable tree structure format. I don't want _id to be part of my tree.

Comment: I used array_shift() function. $array = iterator_to_array($cursor);
               $value = array_shift( $array ); then converted the data to jason object. This works fine now.